# Booting linux from SD Card

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, archlinux

I've a Leopard board with Ti DM365 processor.
Problem is that,I tried to flash the bootloader(uboot) to nand and landed up in corrupting the NAND. Now, i can't use NAND to bring up the board.
So, i decided to use the SD Card.

I did the required partitioning on the SD Card for bootloader / kernel / rootfs

Now, when em restarting the board ...it says...uncompressing the kernel...etc..etc..
but when it tries to look for rootfs...prompt says.."can't find NAND"

I think (em a complete newbie in this field..) Kernel looks into NAND for the "rootfs" instead of SD Card, thats why it is giving that sort of error...

So now I've to configure the kernel in such a way that it should look into SD Card for the "rootfs" instead of looking into NAND (which is corrupted in my case.)

Can any one help me.

Please forgive me if the information is not enough and please ask for more info in needed.
As em a newbie... i dunno what other information i can give...

Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like a [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) sort of question.

Comment: Oh...I didn't know that there is a dedicated section for UNIX/LINUX.
Thanks..!!

Comment: @LevLevitsky disagree - these are kernel compile-time configuration issues, ie programming (porting) rather than usage.

Comment: Do you have uboot on the sdcard? If so you may be able to fix the nand from within uboot without booting the kernel.

Comment: @Chris I thought it was about configuring the bootloader.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I thought it was about compile-time kernel configuration.

Comment: @Chris yes. Uboot is on SD Card. In-fact i've uboot, kernel and rootfs all three on SD Card. But the problem is that, kernel is looking for rootfs on NAND instead of SD Card.

Comment: uboot can be built to have the capability of flashing the nand though, so you might not need to boot linux off the sdcard if you can get to an interactive uboot from it and use that to reflash the nand correctly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for responding..! Sure, i'll try re-flashing uboot to NAND. BUt still, question remains the same...when booting from SD card, why kernel is looking for rootfs on NAND instead of SD Card ? and what can i do to make it look into SD card.

Comment: Hi @mujahid, you should check the bootcmd and the kernel argument bootargs, for mouting the rootfs from SD card, the kernel argument should has something like root=/dev/mmcblk0p1

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make changes in DTS file to create partition for rootfs in the SDcard.

Following is the code snippet from mpc8313erdb.dts where rootfs is present in NAND.

```
    nand@1,0 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "fsl,mpc8313-fcm-nand",
                     "fsl,elbc-fcm-nand";
        reg = <0x1 0x0 0x40000>;

        dtb-0@0 {
            reg = <0x0 0x20000>;
        };

        kernel-0@20000 {
            reg = <0x20000 0x400000>;
        };

        rootfs-0@420000 {
            reg = <0x420000 0x099e0000>;
```

Look for the above file under the following location.
linux/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/[board_name].dts

Check the following link to see the complete DTS file.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts